# Get and Post request result in "error": "Not Found" on my spring boot api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring data JPA to persist an entity to an H2 database, the get/ post requests always return error "Not Found" with status 404, but the data that I send in post request is reaching the database and is saved!

what I tried:
making sure that my controller and the main method are under the same package.

my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/myBudget
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

the controller:

```
package com.example.budgetwithjpa.control;

import com.example.budgetwithjpa.data.ExpenseRepository;
import com.example.budgetwithjpa.entity.Expense;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/budget")
public class ExpenseController {
    ExpenseRepository expenseRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ExpenseController(ExpenseRepository expenseRepo) {
        this.expenseRepo = expenseRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/view")
    public Iterable<Expense> viewAll(Model model) {
        System.out.println(expenseRepo.findAll());
        return expenseRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String addExpense(@RequestBody Expense expense) {
        expenseRepo.save(expense);
        return "ok.";
    }
}
```

in the above code, the `System.out` inside the `viewAll` method will print the contents of the database to console

the repository:

```
import com.example.budgetwithjpa.entity.Expense;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ExpenseRepository extends CrudRepository<Expense, Long> {
}
```

I am sending get request to  http://localhost:8080/budget/view
and getting

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-08-26T11:10:50.956+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/budget/view"
}
```

below are screens of my project file structure and dependencies:

the project file structure:
[image: project file structure]

project dependencies:
[image: dependencies]

you can get the application from [this github repo](https://github.com/Hasan-Alsulaiman/BudgetJPA) if you want to replicate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `@ResponseBody` annotation:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/view")
public Iterable<Expense> viewAll(Model model) {
    System.out.println(expenseRepo.findAll());
    return expenseRepo.findAll();
}
```

Alternatively you could use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: can you maybe upvote my question? I am trying to improve my down-voted questions.